# Can we build an operating system that can be infected by any virus?

Tags: operating-systems

Is it theoretically feasible to engineer a computer (more specifically its operating system)  that is simple and primitive enough to be infected with *any* type of virus? That is, this would be a computer that can execute any type of computer virus regardless of what platform the computer virus was initially designed to attack.

Comment: Mac OS can't run windows apps. Why would a "simple and primitive" OS be able to run any program (virus)?
On the other hand there could be an OS that **can't** be infected by ANY virus -- an OS that doesn't allow external programs to run.

Comment: You would need to give us a definition of a virus and an infection to work with. Regardless of what you choose, I would reckon that the answers would range from "theoretically impossible due to undecidability" to "huh?".

Comment: An operating system which is vulnerable to many different types of viruses will have to be extremely complicated, since each virus exploits a different vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

It is not theoretically possible.

---

A virus is an executable, and like all executables it consists of instructions in an instruction set for a specific hardware or virtual machine architecture.  In addition, an executable depends on libraries and/or syscalls provided by the operating system, and these vary from one OS to the next.  For the sake of argument, let us combine the ISA and the OS architecture into a single thing we'll call a "platform"

Normally, an executable for platform  "B" won't run on a different (incompatible) platform  "A".  However, it possible to implement an emulator for platform  "B" that runs on platform  "A".  If you repeat this for all other possible platforms, then you could *in theory* run *any* executable on platform "A".  That includes any virus.

(This is all very theoretical / hypothetical.  The shear effort involved in implementing emulation layers for all possible platforms is prohibitive ... and pointless.)

---

But then you have the issue that different viruses exploit different vulnerabilities (on their respective target platforms).  For a virus to successfully infect our hypothetical platform "A", the respective emulation layer must exhibit the vulnerabilities that the virus uses.

However, in the real world, some vulnerabilities are introduced when earlier vulnerabilities are fixed.  So virus V1 and V2 may depend on vulnerabilities that cannot *both* exist on a given platform or platform emulation.  In other words, our hypothetical OS cannot be infected by both V1 and V2.